# carousel slide is not working for back end data of images

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have store images in mongodb and fetch from db
all images content are in array i have use angular ng-repeat like as follows

```
    <carousel style=" width: 300px;
height: 300px;
height: auto;
float: left;
margin: 3px;
padding: 3px;">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in data.photos">
          <a class="thumbanails" target="_blank" href="data:image/png;base64,{{slide}}">

        <img ng-hide="!slide" data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{slide}}" alt="no photos"/></a>
     <div flex ng-if="!slide"><img data-ng-src="images/nophoto.jpg" alt="no photos"/></div>
        </slide>
        </carousel>
```

all images are getting at once.
Please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

The normal bootstrap carousel will not work in angular. You have to use the ng-bootstrap carousel. You can find more information [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).

Make sure you have done the following:

1) Install bootstrap CSS with `npm install bootstrap@latest`

2) Install ng-bootstrap with `npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@latest`

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 it working fine for locally stored images but back end stored images are not working

Comment: @satheesh are you using AngularJS or the new Angular?

Comment: i am using an  angular js v1.5.7